# What is the history of this specific Cessna propeller (s/n F2430)?

Tags: propeller, cessna-152, cessna-182, cessna-208, cessna-150

Hoping someone can help... I'm looking to get some information about a Cessna plane propeller my Fiancé recently bought. It's his birthday coming up and it would be great to have any sort of history, photos or further info on his pride and joy.. The information on the propeller:

Cessna KLIPTIP
MET-L-PROP
MCAULEY, DAYTON OHIO
SERIAL NO- F2430
DESIGN 1A100 MCM 6950
T.C 918 P.C.3
I do have photos if necessary

I really would appreciate any sort of help - it would be great to give him a surprise.

Comment: That may help to start: [1A100 MCM](http://www.univair.com/propellers/mccauley/mcm6950-mccauley-propeller/) 6950. FAA TC [P-918](http://150cessna.tripod.com/p-918.pdf). Likely from a [C150 (A-F)](http://www.aircraftspruce.com/catalog/appages/metlprops.php). Looking at the time you posted the question, you may live in Europe and also have bought the propeller here. If so the aircraft may have been built in France by [Reims Aviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reims_Aviation).

Comment: Have you tried contacting [Cessna](http://txtav.com/en/contact) or [McCauley](http://www.mccauley.textron.com/contact.html) directly? They might have info on what aircraft it was originally installed on.